# I have a new library folder created and under Permissions and Management, i don't have access to the Permissions for this document library

Tags: permissions, library, sharepoint-library

I want this to appear 
[image]

Instead i get this

[image]

Why don't i see the link?

Comment: The first thing is to confirm your permission level in the document library.  It looks like from the screen caps you have a permission level that doesn't allow you to modify or inspect permissions.

Answer (score 2):

You have the "Edit" Permission Level, probably as a user in the Member group. You would need to be a Site Owner or have the "Manage Permissions" permission added to your Permission Level.